# How i can check if a <P> inside a <Div> contain data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following field inside my SharePoint office 365 page:-

[image]

here is the related markup:-

```
<div class="ms-rtestate-write ms-rteflags-0 ms-rtestate-field" id="ProjectClosureSummary_cdd30532-e128-4dcd-b9bd-baf3e12a4c04_$TextField_inplacerte" 
    role="textbox" aria-haspopup="true" 
    aria-labelledby="ProjectClosureSummary_cdd30532-e128-4dcd-b9bd-baf3e12a4c04_$TextField_inplacerte_label" style="min-height:84px" contenteditable="true" 
    aria-autocomplete="both" aria-multiline="true" rtedirty="true">
   <p>
    need to ge this text!!
    <span id="ms-rterangecursor-start" rtenodeid="1">
    </span>
    <span id="ms-rterangecursor-end"></span><br>
   </p>
</div>
```

now using javascript or jQuery i need to check if the field contain data? but i am not sure how i can get the text which is inside a `<p>` inside a `<div>`?

Comment: `$('.ms-rtestate-write').find('p').text().length` ?

Comment: Get the text or check the text exists? @Shree has provided the code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try something like this:

```
text = $('p').text();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please take reference from below code:

```js
var parentdiv = document.getElementById('parent');
var childNode = parentdiv.hasChildNodes() ? parentdiv.children[0] : ''
console.log(childNode.textContent || childNode.innerText);
```

```html
<div id="parent"><p>hello world</p></div>
```